# Override aero snap case by case?

Tags: windows-7, aero-snap

It there a way to disable the snapping feature of Aero for a single operation?
For example, sometimes I want to move a window to the top of the screen, but Windows maximizes it. Or extend a window to the top of the screen, but want its bottom to stays as is (Windows will also extend its bottom to the bottom of the screen).

Something like holding SHIFT while dragging the window (or its edge when resizing) to temporarily disable snap would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be prevented if you hold down the Alt key. At least in my limited testing. Have not found it in print anywhere, however.

Comment: Does not work for me on Win7. Tried holding Alt before clicking, after clicking but before moving to the edge and finally after moving to the edge. In all cases the window was maximized. Tried with Notepad and Firefox window. (I have a two monitor)